# Which historical event had the highest number of reported non-fatal injuries without any known deaths?

Tags: records, disasters

It always surprised me that the Chelyabinsk meteor air burst event in Russia in 2013 had over a thousand non-fatal injuries (1491 according to Wikipedia), but not actually any deaths. I'm wondering if there are any known events of any type which had a higher confirmed amount of non-fatal injuries without any known deaths with the event as a direct or indirect cause. I've tried Googling it, but apparently no one has made any lists like that which I can find.

Clarification on definitions: an "event" is something that has taken place at any time in history. It can be a violent incident like a terrorist attack or a riot or a single battle in a war (but not an entire war); It can be a disease outbreak or a natural disaster or even an accident. It can even be a mass epilepsy attack like that Pokémon episode. the only real limitation is that there should be a publicly available historical record of the occurrence. I purposefully want to go as wide as possible because I obviously don't know myself what that event is.

A non-fatal injury is any person who got counted among the injured during the event. For the purposes of this question, it doesn't matter what the nature of the injury is, as long as it got registered. In effect, I don't really care whether it's bruises, temporary blindness, lost limbs, pneumonia, food poisoning, cranial trauma, brain damage, an epileptic seizure, Legionella or anything else, as long as it was counted as an official non-fatal injury. Note that if anyone initially was injured but later died as a direct consequence of that injury, that counts as a death and disqualifies the entire event.

Comment: @MCW It counts as an event, but it would be disqualified because it resulted in deaths.

Comment: Possibly the [Belgian Coca-Cola incident](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/155/2/140/108003)?

Comment: @MCW That incident only appears to cover about a hundred students or so, which doesn't beat the Chelyabinsk meteor.